# Transformation of Area restricted by 3 functions and x-Axis

Tags: measure-theory, transformation, integral-transforms, fubini-tonelli-theorems

With the help of a suitable transformation and Fubini I want to determine the integral
$$
\int_{V} x^{3} y d \lambda_{2}(x, y),
$$
where $V$ is the open subset of $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{2}$ bounded by the following curves:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&x^{2}+y^{2}=4\\
&x^{2}-y^{2}=2 \\
&x^{2}-y^{2}=1
\end{aligned}
$$
I know how to do that. The only problem is finding $V.$ Is it
$$
V=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 1<x^{2}-y^{2}<2, 0< x^{2}+y^{2}<4\}
$$
Because then I set
$$
\begin{aligned}
&x^{2}+y^{2}=v\\
&x^{2}-y^{2}=u 
\end{aligned}
$$
and get
$$
(x,y)=\left(\sqrt{1/2(v-u}),\sqrt{1/2(u+v)}\right)
$$
So either my transformation is wrong or the limits of the intervalls I chose.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
V=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}_+^{2}: x,y>0, x^2+y^2<4, 1<x^2-y^2<2\right\} .
$$
Let us consider the new variables
$$
u=x^2+y^2, \quad v=x^2-y^2
$$
and the corresponding figure
$$
(u, v)=\Psi(x, y):=\left(x^2+y^2, x^2-y^2\right) .
$$
Obviously we have
$$
U:=\Psi(V)=\left\{(u, v) \in \mathbb{R}_+^{2}: 1<v<2,v<u<4\right\} .
$$
The mapping $\Psi: V \rightarrow U$ is continuously differentiable and the inverse mapping $\Phi=\Psi^{-1}$ exists and looks like this:
$$
(x, y)=\Phi(u, v)=\left(\sqrt{\frac{u+v}{2}},\sqrt{\frac{u-v}{2}}\right) .
$$
The mapping $\Phi: U \rightarrow V$ is also continuously differentiable and hence a diffeomorphism. We have
$$
\Phi^{\prime}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\partial_{u} \Phi_{1} & \partial_{v} \Phi_{1} \\
\partial_{u} \Phi_{2} & \partial_{v} \Phi_{2}
\end{array}\right)
=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u+v}} & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u+v}} \\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u-v}} & -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u-v}}
\end{array}\right)
$$
and
$$
\det (\Phi^{\prime})=-\frac{1}{u} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2-v^2}} .
$$
Using the transformation theorem and Fubini's theorem, we obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_{V} x^{3} y \hspace{1mm} d \lambda_{2}(x, y)=\int_{U} x^{3}y \hspace{1mm} |\det (\Phi^{\prime})|\hspace{1mm} d \lambda_{2}(u, v)= \int_{U} \frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{\frac{u+v}{2}}\right)^{3}\sqrt{\frac{u-v}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2-v^2}}  \hspace{1mm} d \lambda_{2}(u, v)\\
 &=\int_1^2\left(\int_v^4 \dfrac{\sqrt{u-v}\left(u+v\right)^\frac{3}{2}}{16\sqrt{u^2-v^2}} du\right) dv =\int_{1}^{2}\left[- \dfrac{3v^2-8v-16}{32}\right]_{v}^{4} d v = \left[-\dfrac{v\left(v^2-4v-16\right)}{32}\right]_1^{2}=\dfrac{21}{32}
\end{aligned}
$$